# Vectrosity insert prefabs with position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I'm currently using Vectrosity to my unity app. I draw lines with touch gestures. Now I would like to insert a text input field at the middle of the created line. Here is my code :

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DrawLinesTouch : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text _Console;


    public Texture2D lineTex;
    public float lineWidth = 4.0f;
    public Texture2D capTex;

    private VectorLine newLine;
    private Vector2 previousPosition;
    private int sqrMinPixelMove;
    //private bool canDraw = false;
    private Touch touch;
    private int _lineIndex;

    public Transform _monCanvas;
    public Transform textfieldPrefab;


    void Start () {     
        VectorLine.SetEndCap ("flech", EndCap.Mirror, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, lineTex, capTex);
        _lineIndex = 0;
        SetLine ();
    }

    void SetLine() {
        newLine = new VectorLine("line_"+_lineIndex.ToString(), new List<Vector2>(),lineTex, lineWidth, LineType.Discrete, Joins.None);
        newLine.endCap = "flech";
        _lineIndex++;
    }

    void Update () {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
            touch = Input.GetTouch (0);
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {


                SetLine ();


                newLine.points2.Add (touch.position);

                if (newLine.points2.Count == 1) {

                    newLine.points2.Add (Vector2.zero);

                    _Console.text = newLine.points2.Count.ToString();

                }
            } 

            if (newLine.points2.Count >= 2 && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
                _Console.text = "Moved ?";
                newLine.points2[newLine.points2.Count-1] = touch.position;
                newLine.Draw();

            }


            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {              

                _Console.text = "Fin de la ligne " + newLine.name;

                Transform dimValue = (Transform) Instantiate(textfieldPrefab, new Vector2(?????), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));

                dimValue.transform.SetParent (_monCanvas, false);



            }
        }

    }


}
```

I created a prefab which is Instantiate (line 66), but no idea how to set the text input at the middle of the line. I suppose that I need to get the position and length of the drawn line.

Any idea ? Thanks!

Comment: What if the drawn line is not straight...How do you determine the middle point? By the way, you can find middle line of a straightline with **(PosA + PosB)/2**.

Comment: I always draw straight lines. My issue is here : Transform dimValue = (Transform) Instantiate(textfieldPrefab, new Vector2(?????), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)); How can I say instead of ??? -> set the prefab at the middle of the line

Comment: I know what your issue is. The solution is not magic. You need to do some calculation to find that position...Did you see my **(PosA + PosB)/2** comment?